# Dynamic linq expression for filtering with enum collection

Tags: c#, linq, enums

```
public enum StoreType {
    Children = 1,
    Adult = 2,
    Farm = 3
}
```

If I have a collection of these:

```
List<StoreType> enumCollection = new List<StoreType>{ StoreType.Children, StoreType.Farm };
```

And I want to build dynamic linq expression so I can foreach through enum types to filter results based on those enums?

pseudo code what I want to achieve:

```
var enumFilter = LinqExpressionHelper.BuildEnumFilter(enumCollection);
    _storeRepository.GetStores.Where(enumFilter).ToList();
```

How can I build a dynamic linq expression so I can filter by enum collection?

Comment: Use .Contains() instead of .Where().

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `Contains` on the list:

```
_storeRepository.GetStores.Where(store => enumCollection.Contains(store.Type)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood what you wanted

```
List<StoreType> filters = new List<StoreType> { StoreType.Children, StoreType.Farm };
List<int> lstTofilter = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var filteredList = lstTofilter.Where(i => !filters.Any(e => i.Equals((int)e))); //2, 4, 5
```

remember to cast the enums to integers to retrieve their value

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var enumCollection = new List<StoreType> { StoreType.Children, StoreType.Farm };

        var repo = new StoreRepository();

        var enumFilter = LinqExpressionHelper.BuildEnumFilter(enumCollection);
        var result  = repo.GetStores().Where(enumFilter).ToList();

        foreach (var store in result)
            Console.WriteLine($"Name={store.Name}, Type={store.StoreType}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public enum StoreType
{
    Children = 1,
    Adult = 2,
    Farm = 3
}

public class StoreRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Store> GetStores()
    {
        return new List<Store>
        {
            new Store {Name = "NewYork", StoreType = StoreType.Adult},
            new Store {Name = "RioDeJaneiro", StoreType = StoreType.Farm},
            new Store {Name = "Budapest", StoreType = StoreType.Children}
        };
    }
}

public class Store
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public StoreType StoreType { get; set; }
}

public static class LinqExpressionHelper
{
    public static Func<Store, bool> BuildEnumFilter(IEnumerable<StoreType> storeTypes)
    {
        return store => storeTypes.Contains(store.StoreType);
    }
}
```